# Receiving "invalid or does not take any parameters" when attempting to deploy a contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, pragma, erc20

here is my 2_deploy_contract.js syntax

```
 const DerbyToken = artifacts.require("./DerbyToken.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  // Deploy the Migrations contract as our only task
  deployer.deploy(DerbyToken);
};
```

after I migrate the file using truffle I receive this error message

```
    Error: Migration /home/cyraidz/token_sale/migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js invalid or does not take any parameters
    at Migration._load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:55:1)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
Truffle v5.3.5 (core: 5.3.5)
Node v10.19.0
```

Comment: Share the DerbyToken contract code. especially the constructor

Answer (score 0):

Add a newline at the end of "2_deploy_contract.js"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).